# Alpha is ignored in my pixel array when using CGBitmapContextCreate

Tags: ios, objective-c, quartz-core

I am trying to draw an image with coregraphics using an array of pixels.

My image is 568x320 and here is my code :

```
int k = 0;
unsigned char pixels[320 * 568*4];
for(int i = 0; i<568/1;i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j<320/1;j++) {
        pixels[k] = 212; //B
        pixels[k+1] = 2; //G
        pixels[k+2] = 87;//R
        pixels[k+3] = drand48()*255; //A
        k+=4;
    }
}
void *baseAddress = &pixels;


NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, 568, 320, 8, 4*568, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

CGContextRelease(context);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

UIImage *textureImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
```

Basically, the colour looks right, but there is no transparency. if the alpha is 0, the image is black, else it's blue.

Any idea why I'm getting no transparency ?

EDIT:

Here is my result and the result I expect with Alpha

[image: current result]
[image: expected result]

I got the second result with

```
for(int i = 0; i<568/1;i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j<320/1;j++) {
       [[UIColor colorWithRed:87./255 green:2.0/255 blue:212.2/255 alpha:drand48()] setFill];
       CGContextFillRect(ctx, CGRectMake(i, j, 1, 1));
    }
 }
```

but it's extremely slow compared to CGBitmapContextCreate

Comment: Have you tried "normal" settings with rgb order and `kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast` flag alone?

Comment: What do you mean normal settings ? going ARGB instead of BGRA ?

Comment: I meant rgba (hence `kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast` flag).

Comment: I still get the same colour everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `CGBitmapContextCreate` incorrectly. First argument is a **destination**, not data source. You don't even need to create bitmap context to create CGImage. Check following code.

```
int k = 0;
unsigned char pixels[320*568*4];
for(int i=0; i<568; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<320; j++) {
        pixels[k] = 87; //R
        pixels[k+1] = 2; //G
        pixels[k+2] = 212; //B
        pixels[k+3] = drand48()*255; //A
        k+=4;
    }
}

CGDataProviderRef data = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, &pixels, 320*568*4*sizeof(char), NULL);
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

CGImageRef cgImg = CGImageCreate(568, 320, 8, 4*8, 4*568, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault | kCGImageAlphaLast, data, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
UIImage *textureImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImg];

CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
CGDataProviderRelease(data);
CGImageRelease(cgImg);
```

If you want to change colours order then play with `kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault | kCGImageAlphaLast` flags.

Btw. why are you dividing by 1 in loop conditions?

Comment: It worked thanks. I was dividing by 1 as earlier I was divided by two for testing purposes and just put a 1 to type in quicker. Thank you